# Integrally closed domains, where is the reduced hypothesis used?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, commutative-algebra, localization

The question is to show, given a local domain $A$, with maximal ideal $(\pi)$, $B$ a domain containing $A$,  $S=A-(\pi)$. If $S^{-1}B$ is integrally closed, and $B/\pi B$ reduced, then $B$ is integrally closed.

My proof is to take $x\in\mathrm{Quot}(B)$ integral over $B$, this will be integral over $S^{-1}B$, so will be contained in $S^{-1}B$, thus there exists $s\in A-(\pi)$ with $sx\in B$.

But in $A$, $s$ is a unit, so is a unit in $B$, so $x\in B$, and we are done.

This argument doesn't use that the maximal ideal is principle, or the reduced hypothesis, so I suspect there's an error somewhere, but I cant see where.

Comment: I have a guess: $S=\{1,\pi,\pi^2,\dots\}$.

Comment: From what you said $S$ consists of units of $B$, so $S^{-1}B = B$. Like user26857, I suspect that you have $S$ backwards

Comment: Thanks, I'm guessing there is a typo somewhere in the question, since it is stated as $A-(\pi)$, but this doesn't make much sense. $A-(0)$ makes more sense, given that tensor products aren't used in the book, possibly explaining the weird notation.

Comment: I don't think it's supposed to be $S = A - (0)$ because in that case, taking $B$ to be any ring between $A$ and its field of fractions $K$, you would have $S^{-1}B = K$ and the assumption that $S^{-1}B$ is integrally closed would become trivial.  In particular, you'd have to exclude the case $A=B$ for any nonintegrally closed $A$.  Taking $S$ as in @user26857 does work out and is a fun exercise.

Comment: As an example take a valuation domain of rank greater than $1$, where the two rings of fraction are different.